# Is there an English word for adopting a new habit?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:
I have started reading comics. This is the new habit I have adopted.
So I want to tell people "hey, comics is my <***that English word***>"

Comment: "new thing", "new obsession", "new time-sink',"current addiction", "interest de-jour" would be two word ways I could hear people saying that they have something new that they're engrossed in. I'm not sure if you're looking for a word that omits the word "is" though.. so I might be missing the question too.

Comment: You can call it your passion.  The word is commonly used that way.

Comment: How about *kick*?

Comment: None of the suggestions on this page work without additionally qualifying them with *new*. So all this question becomes is looking for a better word for *habit*. Of which there are dozens waiting for you in a thesaurus of your choice, of which there are hundreds.

Answer (score 1):

A habit is an action taken repeatedly, such as the habit of adding cream to a cup of coffee. Partaking in a hobby is not generally considered a habit. Comics is not an exact activity. I would say, "Hey, reading comics is my hobby."

Answer (score 1):

*Hey, discussing comics is my new hobbyhorse.*

> **hobbyhorse**
>   [...]
>   4a :  a topic to which one constantly reverts
>   b  :  hobby
>
> Another meaning of hobbyhorse was "a favorite pursuit or pastime"; our modern noun hobby ("an activity that one does for pleasure when not working") was formed by shortening this word. From "pastime," the meaning of hobbyhorse was extended to "a subject to which one repeatedly returns."  The sense is typically encountered as part of such metaphorical phrases as "get on one's hobbyhorse" or "ride one's hobbyhorse."
>   — https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hobbyhorse

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is a specific idiom or phrase for "this new thing I'm doing," but you might try exploring synonyms for "hobby" such as a *vocation, passion, bailiwick, bag*, or, simply, *hobby*.

I also have to be picky on your is/are. "Comics" ends with an "s" and so "are" should be used.

- *Hey, comics are my new hobby* = simple, somewhat trite.
- *Hey, comics are my new bag* = "slang-y"
- *Hey, comics are my new bailiwick* = quirky
- *Hey, comics are my new avocation* = professional

Answer (score 0):

> Reading comics is my new pastime.

This means my new way to spend my free time is to read comics.

> ***[Pastime](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pastime)*** (Random House):  something, as a game, sport, or hobby, that serves to make time pass agreeably.